# Calling an API that have username and password in Java

Tags: java, api

I'm trying to connect to an API that has a username and password with this code:

```
try {
    URL url = new URL("https://url?UserName=username&Password=password");
    Connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

    //Request setup
    Connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
    Connection.setConnectTimeout(5000);
    Connection.setReadTimeout(5000);
    int status = Connection.getResponseCode();
    System.out.println(status);

}
catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

But I get the error:

> java.net.SocketException: Connection reset

I kept searching and I found another format for the URL which is:

```
URL url = new URL("Https:username:password@url);
```

When I tried, it gave me the error:

> java.net.MalformedURLException: For input string:password@url

I tried to separate the URL into three strings and made the password Integer.pharsInt("String"), but it also didn't work.
The password has words, numbers, and a special character!

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The `MalformedURLException` can be fixed by using `https://username:password@url`. You're missing those //.

Comment: added it but still the same

Comment: I'm guessing you need to URLEncode your password (and possibly your username). URLs are limited in what they allow; good passwords often contain characters that are not valid in URLs.

Answer (score 0):

Try to encode your URL, this way:

```
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)
    new URL("https://url?UserName" +
            URLEncoder.encode(username, "UTF-8") +
            "&Password=" +
            URLEncoder.encode(password, "UTF-8"))
            .openConnection();

connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();

BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"));

// The rest of your code
```

Comment: A small improvement if you're using Java 10 or higher. URLEncoder.encode has been overloaded to accept a Charset instead of a String encoding. That overloaded version doesn't throw any checked exceptions.: `URLEncoder.encode(username, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)`.

Comment: Is curiosity you mentioned Charset instead of a String encoding from Java 10 or  higher. I'm using Java 11. so I got that problem and I needed to add URLEncoder, which contains characters not valid in URLs.

Comment: I agree that you still need to use URLEncoder, what I said that you can replace the `UTF-8` String inside `URLEncoder.encode` with `StandardCharsets.UTF_8`.